# c# tcp programming a simple way to transfer binary file from client to server

Tags: c#, python, sockets, tcp

I am doing my project about TCP server and client, so this project I want to transfer a binary file like:

- .exe
- .jpg
- .docx
- .txt
- .dll
- and etc..

I already try so many different ways in my code to transfer the file and still failed.

Problem I got when using this code, transfer file more then size of 9kb:

```
byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

1. Everything fine because I read all bytes inside the file
2. After that I sent it to server using:

   ```
   stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
   ```
3. Client successfully sent the data to server
4. On server the code is like this to receive the file data from client:

   ```
   recv = "";
   byte[] bb = new byte[8000000];
   int k = control.Receive(bb);
   for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
       recv += Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
   rec = Convert.ToString(recv);
   byte[] array = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rec);
   File.WriteAllBytes(filename, array);
   MessageBox.Show("download success!");
   ```
5. So server successfully receive the data from client and server encode it
   to byte array and save the data into file using this:

   ```
   File.WriteAllBytes(filename, array);
   ```

The problem is

1. The file that I sent was more then 9 kb size
2. When server write the data in file it just corrupt the file
   and the size file not same as exactly the actual file size from client

So what the problem I have here? And how to solve it?

If python its easy to get big data using timeout like this code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
from thread import *
import time
import random
def recv_timeout(socket,timesz):
    socket.setblocking(0)
        total_data=[]
        data=""
        begin=time.time()
        while 1:
            if total_data and time.time()-begin >timesz:
                break
            elif time.time()-begin > timesz*2:
                break
            try:
                data = socket.recv(8192)
                if data:
                    total_data.append(data)
                    begin=time.time()
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            except:
                pass
    return ''.join(total_data)
```

I use this code to receive big data and its successful receive a jpg file.. is it possible to use this method from python on C#?

Answer (score 0):

For your python code, there is no need in reading unblocking and doing the blocking yourself. All the waiting and timeout mechanisms are builtin to your socket:

```
def recv_all(socket):
    total_data = []
    while True:
        data = socket.recv(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        total_data.append(data)
    return ''.join(total_data)
```

You have to do the same in your C#-code: receive data until the socket on the sending side is closed.

```
recv = "";
int k;
do {
    byte[] bb = new byte[8000];
    k = control.Receive(bb);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        recv += Convert.ToChar(bb[i]);
} while(k);
```

Comment: seems, `k` has to be defined outside the loop.

Comment: sorry i forgot to defined k from outside loop.. so i change everything then this error [Link](https://ibb.co/nraiH5)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need encode all bytes to string. Try this code:

```
var chunkSize = 8000000;
byte[] bb = new byte[chunkSize];
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(filename))
{
    while (true)
    {
        var bytesReceived = control.Receive(bb);
        file.Write(bb, 0, bytesReceived);
        if (bytesReceived < chunkSize)
            break;
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("download success!");
```